# HI I am trying to prevent inserting the same DATE for the same user. Trigger generates an error stating that it is not mutable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

HI I am trying to prevent inserting the same DATE for the same user. Trigger generates an error stating that it is not mutable. Is there any way to fix it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER fake_trig
  BEFORE INSERT ON newtable
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   testtr1        NUMBER;
   testtr1       Date;
   testtr1   EXCEPTION;

 BEGIN
  SELECT 
         CHECKTB1,
         CHECKTTB2
  INTO   
         testtr1,
         testtr1

  FROM   newtable
  WHERE  :NEW.checktb1 = CHECKTB1;

    IF :new.checkttb2 = testtr1 THEN
      RAISE testtr1;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN testtr1 THEN
    Raise_application_error(-20300,'not working');
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        NULL;
END;
```

Comment: Your code will not generate that error message; it generates multiple errors relating to `PLS-00371: at most one declaration for 'TESTTR1' is permitted`

Comment: *"Not mutable"*, or *"Table is mutating"*?

Answer (score 2):

A trigger is inappropriate for this task. This is something that should be enforced using a  `UNIQUE` constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE newtable
  ADD CONSTRAINT newtable__checktb1_checkttb2__u UNIQUE (checktb1, checkttb2);
```

---

If you did want to use a trigger (don't, this should be handled by a constraint) then all you need to do is fix the variables so they are not all named identically:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER fake_trig
  BEFORE INSERT ON newtable
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   testtr1 NUMBER;
   testtr2 Date;
   testtr3 EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  SELECT CHECKTB1,
         CHECKTTB2
  INTO   testtr1,
         testtr2
  FROM   newtable
  WHERE  :NEW.checktb1 = CHECKTB1;

  IF :new.checkttb2 = testtr2 THEN
    RAISE testtr3;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN testtr3 THEN
    Raise_application_error(-20300,'not working');
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

*Note: you should give variables meaningful names so that you can tell what they each represent.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e0083e45f48cd7c8ca0a9ce34050be6a)*

Comment: The trigger approach will still throw ORA-04091 [with `insert ... select`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a67f6e40bef5d3ec52fb820326e85e52); and the OP's code also doesn't allow more than two dates for a user, presumably by accident. But all of that just reinforces why a constraint should be used *8-)